# Attempting to return view model of SelectListItem dropdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Unregister(LinkedServiceTable lst)
    {
        lst.BuildLinkedServices();
        var model = new LinkedServiceTableViewModel
        {
            LinkedServices = GetLinkedServices(lst)
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Unregister(LinkedServiceTableViewModel vm)
    {
        return View(vm);
    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetLinkedServices(LinkedServiceTable lst)
    {
        var roles = lst.LinkedServices.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.LinkedServiceId.ToString(),
            Text = x.ServiceName
        });
        return new SelectList(roles, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

Here is my razor view

```
@model CDIWeb.ViewModels.LinkedServiceTableViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Unregister Linked Service";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

<form action="/LinkedService/Unregister" method="post">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLinkedServiceId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLinkedServiceId, Model.LinkedServices)
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

All I want to do is submit myrazor view, then redirect back to the same page with the submited option on the dropdown selected.  However, I am getting this error on `HttpPost` view, the `HttpGet` view is working fine and I am able to submit successfully.

> InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedLinkedServiceId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I believe that error means that `Model.LinkedServices` is null, and as a result it thinks your first parameter is the list of select items.

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry, for further clarification, my HttpGet view is fine, I get the correct dropdown, but when I click submit and it redirects to the HttpPost view, i get that error.

Comment: Yeah, mostly likely because `LinkedServiceTableViewModel` does not contain an instantiated `LinkedServices` list (as in, it is null).

Comment: How can it be null if the `LinkedServices` are correctly displayed in the HttpGet? The `LinkedServiceTableViewModel` is built in the HttpGet Unregister Action, the page is displayed, the LinkedServices are correctly displayed in the dropdown, and that same object is then passed to the unregister HttpPost action.  How can it become nulled later?

Comment: Get and Post are two different requests.

Comment: @TravisJ I know but my Get model (which is working) is being passed to my post.

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the way data moves in these requests.

Comment: Please show where the model is "being passed" to your post method.

Comment: Hmm alright, nevermind I understand the issue and why I need to re-add the LinkedServices. One final question, `LinkedServiceTable` is a dependency injection which is a singleton.  `BuildLinkedServices` just puts some example services into the `LinkedServiceTable.LinkedServices` property.  If I `BuildLinkedServices` in the HttpGet, why do I need to build it again in HttpPost? Is there anyway to avoid this? I want each build to update the singleton, since a singleton should be a constant class through all calls.

Comment: A dependency injection at the ActionResult level? Are you sure, from my understanding dependency injection occurs at the controller level.

Comment: I am dependency injecting into specific ActionResults, which is the standard method from my research. `public IActionResult Unregister(LinkedServiceTable lst)`  then `LinkedServiceTable` would be  injected for example. So at the ActionResult level in the Controller class.

Comment: Which DI container are you using?

Comment: Just the normal `IServiceCollection` which is configured in the startup class.  `services.AddSingleton<LinkedServiceTable>();`

Comment: In addition to the dupe, your `GetLinkedServices()` method should have just `return roles;` (using `new SelectList(...)` to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from `roles` is pointless extra overhead)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you will need to fill the DropDownList with data again, because those data doesn't persist between postbacks.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Unregister(LinkedServiceTableViewModel lst)
{
    // Do something, and display the page again with data.

    lst.BuildLinkedServices();
    lst.LinkedServices = GetLinkedServices(lst);
    return View(lst);
}
```

Comment: My post is having the issue, not get.  The get is working fine.

Comment: I updated the answer. You still need to re-fill the LinkedServices.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this in the past by doing the following.

Create an `IEnumerable`:

```
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Unregister Linked Service";

     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList =
         from cf in Model.LinkedServices
         select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Selected = cf."your value",
                        Text = cf."your value",
                        Value = cf."your value"
                    };
}
```

Then after you create the `IEnumerable` list, just use it in your razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLinkedServiceId, selectList)
```

Comment: Okay thanks, i will try that.  However I am curious, what is different between that and creating the IEnumerable on the controller level like I am doing at the moment?